# Document listener jQuery.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

We have a web app that spits out elements server-side and some through Backbone -- and have  a simple `jQuery.each()` statement that flips through elements on the page and adds/removes certain classes based on size of the component. I'm calling this within an "init" function, but it's obviously not working for any elements that are not on the page when loaded; within the Backbone scope.

I'd rather not re-call this function in each Backbone instance (in-case we end up adding more views that render other items needed by this function) and wanted something like a `$(document).on()` function to work like I do for normal clicks, hovers, etc. I haven't found any examples on how I could make this work with `jQuery.each()`, so would appreciate any insight on how I'd go about this.

Comment: There is no magic solution to modifying dynamically loaded content. You need to run that code on the loaded panel, just after it is loaded. Only CSS styling and events can be handled dynamically by all browsers.

Comment: Create a function that does the modifying. Have that function accept a jQuery object. In your `each`, call that function and pass in the object. When you load in new html, call that same function passing in a jquery object.

Comment: As TrueBlueAussie stated, you can't dynamically be notified on these things. If it's something that having a response rate of ~500ms is good enough for, you could set run the each statement every ~500ms and set processed elements as dirty, and only run your selector on non-dirty elements.

Comment: Looks like I can use mutation observers for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

[Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) are what I'll go with.